# How to attach PlaceID for share video on Facebook in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-places-api

I am trying to share Video on Facebook when user click on custom share UIButton().

```
let video = Video(url: videourl)

var content = VideoShareContent(video: video)

// If I am removing this line, its upload to Facebook.
content.placeId = "166793820034304"    //Custom placeId

let sharer = GraphSharer(content: content)
sharer.failsOnInvalidData = false

do {
    try sharer.share()
} catch let err {
    print(err.localizedDescription)
}

sharer.completion = { FBresult in

    switch FBresult {
    case .failed(let error):
        print(error)
        break
    case .success(_):
        print("Uploaded")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

What is the solution to share video on Facebook with place/placeId?